# Counting number of messages for a mailbox over several periods

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails, active-record

The idea is to return a number of messages received today, this week, this month.

```
  def index
    @mailboxes = current_user.mailboxes
    @today, @month, @week, @all_time = 0, 0, 0, 0

    @mailboxes.each do |mailbox|
      @today += mailbox.messages.today.length
      @month += mailbox.messages.week.length
      @week += mailbox.messages.month.length
      @all_time += mailbox.messages.length
    end
  end
```

week, month scopes are similar to the following one

```
  scope :today, -> { where(created_at: ((Time.zone.now - 24.hours)..Time.zone.now)) }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some suggestions ...

Use a counter cache for messages on `Mailbox` -- the count of `all` can be read from the `mailbox` instance.

Use `#size` instead of `#length`. This will use a counter cache for messages on `Mailbox` if one is present, or will use a SQL `count`. `#length` will get all of the messages back, then check the size of the array.

I would be concerned about having multiple mailboxes. If your user model `has_many :messages, through: :mailbox` you can run these queries more efficiently:

```
messages = current_user.messages

@today    = messages.today.size
@week     = messages.week.size
@month    = messages.month.size
@all_time = messages.size
```

With a counter cache, you're only running three queries to get the counts, and thy should be efficient enough.

Place a single index on the columns `(user_id, id)` on the `mailboxes` tables, and an index on `(mailbox_id, created_at)` on the `messages` table.

Edit: I just noticed the `week` and `month` variable assignments were round the wrong way. Also, if you wanted to be slightly more efficient you could define a scope for `week_except_today` and `month_except_week`, etc, and then:

```
@today    = messages.today.size
@week     = @today + messages.week_except_today.size
@month    = @week  + messages.month_except_week.size
@all_time = messages.size
```

Answer (score 1):

As David points out you are going to run four queries. The `size` method will actually run more efficient sql, and *not* load the objects into memory which is also more efficient if you don't need the actual objects.

Also 
 `scope :today, -> { where(created_at: ((Time.zone.now - 24.hours)..Time.zone.now)) }`
does not print out todays' messages but rather those from the last 24 hours. You could use the `beginning_of_day` method to get the start of today.